# Issue installing Apache2-utils on Linux

Tags: linux

When I go to install using command - sudo yum install apache2-utils.  I get the following - No package apache-utils available.

When I run sudo yum update I get the following error: What does this error message mean?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B25Wo.png)

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686 != 
libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.53.1-6.el7_9.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: systemd-libs-219-78.el7_9.2.i686 != systemd-libs-219-73.el7_8.8.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: krb5-libs-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 != krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Are you using official CentOS repos or some other repos (like an internal mirror)?

Comment: Not sure, its RedHat OS, not sure about repos

Comment: If it's actual RHEL that's slightly different. Either way you should first find out what Linux distribution it is and let us know. Also you should post the rest of the message as you have left out detail both before and after the part you posted.